# Saturn Ion clutch pedal and clutch master cylinder push rod equivalents

Tags: clutch, saturn, ion

I need to replace the clutch pedal and clutch master cylinder push rod on my 2006 Saturn Ion. The clutch pedal is getting hard to find. Rather than paying more than I can afford and waiting for it to get shipped, I'm hoping 
to find something compatible at a junkyard (the local manual Ions are already stripped). Are there any other cars that had a compatible clutch pedal? Any cars with a compatible clutch master cylinder?

Comment: Who made the master cylinder?

Comment: @SolarMike: That I don't know, but I'll try to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Check eBay -

[OEM Saturn Ion Clutch Master Cylinder](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Saturn-GM-OEM-03-07-Ion-Clutch-Master-Cylinder-12581771/131707783409?epid=658332031&hash=item1eaa6548f1:g:utEAAOSwz71ZS5HN)

Doesn't seem like $51 and free shipping would be too much for a complete clutch master with the rod as well.  There's 188 of them already sold on that listing, so that's saying something about the failure rate/need for this part.  Now as far as the clutch *pedal*, that seems available but eyewater-expensive at around $170... but it does include the bracket and the whole assembly.  Try searching on GM 15274047.

Unfortunately, the "junkyard" route, if you can find one, will probably get you an inexpensive part that is nearly worn out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I had already seen the online options. It's the expense of the pedal I was referring to. The master cylinder is also still carried by parts stores, some at about the same price. I included the master cylinder in the question in case someone knew of another car that used it, but the person didn't know about the pedal.

Comment: What's wrong with the pedal?  Perhaps it could be repaired ... sleeve the worn out pivot area, weld up the bracket and rebore the hinge pin...  I dunno.  Sounds like it's time to pony up or get out of dodge.  I'm super cheap so I'd probably be resorting to coat hangers and JB Weld: whatever it takes.  The vehicle is probably very sound otherwise - I had a buddy with an L. Also a stick.  I used to "maintain" it, such as welding up the flexible exhaust pipe under the oil pan.  He eventually sold it at 268,000 miles, 140K more than he bought it with, and got 75% of what he had in it.

Comment: The engines are super solid and reliable.  It's a damn shame GM abandoned Saturn.  Good luck and find or fix that pedal.

Comment: The well where the push rod sockets was worn down. Funny you should mention JB Weld; short term, I've built up the worn area with epoxy putty (though I wish I had mixed in something fibrous) and coated it with polyurethane. Between that and the clutch bleed, the car no longer suffers a short clutch.